# how to get the id name in html for any object

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am calling method onClick function on the img and i want that image id to use further so how to access that image id

```
  con.innerHTML += '<table id="results" width="915" border="1" style="margin:-46px 0 0 -2px;"><tr><td><input id="chkbox'+j+'" type="checkbox" name="click_1" value="">&nbsp;'
        + str
        + '</td><td colspan="4" align="right"><a href="javascript:presenter.command(\'viewPdf\',{\'path\': \'/images/pdf/animal/Beef/'+j+'.pdf\'});"><img src="images/view.png" style="margin-left:250px;"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/email.png" id="'+j+'" onClick=mytest()></td></tr>'+ break_line +'<img src="images/line.png" style="margin-bottom:-47px;"></table>';
```

here is the function i want to store the id of image which is j in this

```
     function mytest(){

     var ab=document.getElementById('j');

     alert("ali this is wokring fine");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using inline event attributes, just do this:

```
onClick='mytest(this)'
```

...which passes a reference to the clicked element into your function:

```
function mytest(clickedElement) {
    var theId = clickedElement.id;
}
```

You can then access any of the properties of the element in question. I've shown how to get the `id`, but you may not need the `id`, because if you already have a reference to the element you can obviously then work with it directly - given that it's an img, you could, for example, change its `src`:

```
clickedElement.src = "someotherimg.jpg";
```

Note that you don't then need `getElementById()` at all.

UPDATE: To answer the "what if?" in the comment, you can setup `mytest()` to receive an id:

```
function mytest(elId) {
    var ab = document.getElementById(elId);
    // etc
}
```

And then you can call it both from an `onclick` handler:

```
onclick='mytest(this.id);'
```

...and directly in your code if the id is already known:

```
mytest('1');
mytest('2');
var someId = '3';
mytest(someId);
```

Comment: what if i want to call this mytest using id like not onClick becuase i have more than 100 pdf which i want that if id 0 then open 1 and 2 then 2 like this so instead of callin mytest can we call by id simple

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover what you seem to be asking in the comment.

Comment: can you please help me out that how to concate this var of id in pdf name

Comment: You'd use the `+` operator, like you already do in the code in your original post. `'/images/pdf/animal/Beef/'+elId+'.pdf\'` - or similar.

Comment: i am not getting this can you write full code as i added please

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is this:

```
<img id="some_id" src="images/email.png" onclick="mytest(this)">

function mytest (img) {
  alert(img.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass j inside mytest

```
+ '</td><td colspan="4" align="right"><a href="javascript:presenter.command(\'viewPdf\',{\'path\': \'/images/pdf/animal/Beef/'+j+'.pdf\'});"><img src="images/view.png" style="margin-left:250px;"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/email.png" id="'+j+'" onClick="mytest('+j+');"></td></tr>'+ break_line +'<img src="images/line.png" style="margin-bottom:-47px;"></table>';
```

JS:

```
function mytest(id){

     var ab=document.getElementById(id);

     alert("ali this is wokring fine");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Image tag call the `Mytest()` function like below

```
onClick='mytest(this);'
```

**Javascript :**

```
function mytest(imgEle) {
   var ab=imgEle.id;
   alert("ali this is wokring fine");
}
```